# How to Perform Aggregate on Each Data Frame at once in R?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, dataframe, aggregate

I have thousands of `.csv` files consists of year and HS information which looks like this:

```
Year  HS
1956  1.06
1956  1.07
....
2012  0.95
```

Each csv file represent different location.
What I should be doing are:

1. Found Maximum HS for each Year on each file
2. Create thousands separate `.csv` files which hold information of point 1

So, basically I am repeating a same task for each file.

However, after input all files to data frame with name `df1,df2,df3...`, I am stuck to perform `aggregate` for each data frame (unable to looping through data frame). I don't know how to 'call' the data frames:

```
    temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
  assign(paste0("df",i),
         read.table(temp[i],header=TRUE,sep=";"))
}
for (i in 1:length(temp))
{
  assign(paste0("ag",i),
         aggregate(HS~Year,data=df(i),max))
}
```

I use those script and it show:

```
Error in df[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Then I change to:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
  assign(paste0("df",i),
         read.table(temp[i],header=TRUE,sep=";"))
}
for (i in 1:length(temp))
{
  assign(paste0("ag",i),
         aggregate(HS~Year,data=df(i),max))
}
```

And it show:

```
Error in df(i) : argument "df1" is missing, with no default
```

I try to work with data list (although I haven't really understand) and write this script:

```
    temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
  assign(paste0("df",i),
         read.table(temp[i],header=TRUE,sep=";"))
}
dfl=mget(ls(pattern="df[1-length(temp)]"))
for (i in 1:length(dfl)){
       assign(paste0("ag",i),
              aggregate(HS~Year,data=dfl[i],max))
}
```

But it doesn't work and show:

```
  Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'HS' not found
```

I don't think that there is any problem with input since it's work when I perform `aggregate` and `write.csv` to single dataframe (without looping).
Is there any suggestion for this problem?

Thank you.

Anyway, I am new in R. Like... literally new, less than 30 hours hahaha. So, I realize that I may be writing inefficient script. I will be glad if there is anyone who also want to suggest better script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the file names, `files`, read them in giving a list of data frames, `L`, and apply `aggregate` to each one. `Ag` will be a list of the aggregated data frames.

```
files <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
L <- lapply(files, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = ";")
Ag <- lapply(L, aggregate, formula = HS ~ Year, FUN = max)
```

or if you don't need or can't afford to store L conbine the last two lines into:

```
Ag <- lapply(files, 
 function(f) aggregate(HS ~ Year, read.table(f, header = TRUE, sep = ";"), max))
```

Comment: It said:
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Honestly, `read.csv` doesn't seems work to my data. Previously i input my csv file using `read.csv`, it store to 1 variable and i wasn't able to perform aggregate even for single dataframe.

Comment: I have changed it to read.table under the assumption that the read.table command in your code works.